# Ошибка в unit-тесте бота vk (vk_api)

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, юнит-тесты, mock

Прошу помочь разобраться с ошибкой.
Пишу юнит тест для чат бота вк.
Тестируемая функция:

```
 def on_event(self, event):
        """
        Send message back if it's text.
        :param event: VkBotMessageEvent object
        :return: None
        """
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            log.debug('отправляем сообщение назад')
            self.api.messages.send(
                message=event.object.message['text'],
                random_id=random.randint(0, 2 ** 20),
                peer_id=event.object.message['peer_id'],
            )
        else:
            log.info('неизвестное событие %s', event.type)
```

Unit-тест:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock, ANY

from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotMessageEvent

from bot import Bot


class Test1(TestCase):
    RAW_EVENT = {
        'type': 'message_reply',
        'object': {'date': 1582978048, 'from_id': *******, 'id': 71, 'out': 1, 'peer_id': ******,
                   'text': 'wdwd', 'conversation_message_id': 70, 'fwd_messages': [], 'important': False,
                   'random_id': 0, 'attachments': [], 'admin_author_id': *****, 'is_hidden': False},
        'group_id': *******,
        'event_id': '274225226747bb8ac5229a667f0deaa9a1f38d72'}

    def test_on_event(self):
        event = VkBotMessageEvent(raw=self.RAW_EVENT)

        send_mock = Mock()

        with patch('bot.vk_api.VkApi'):
            with patch('bot.VkBotLongPoll'):
                bot = Bot('', '')
                bot.api = Mock()
                bot.api.messages.send = send_mock

                bot.on_event(event)

        send_mock.assert_called_once_with(
            message=self.RAW_EVENT['object']['text'],
            random_id=ANY,
            peer_id=self.RAW_EVENT['object']['peer_id'],
        )
```

Ошибка:

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\unittest\case.py", line 60, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "C:\Python38\lib\unittest\case.py", line 676, in run
    self._callTestMethod(testMethod)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\unittest\case.py", line 633, in _callTestMethod
    method()
  File "*******\tests.py", line 50, in test_on_event
    send_mock.assert_called_once_with(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 918, in assert_called_once_with
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: Expected 'send' to be called once. Called 0 times.
```

Самая функция из `mock.ru` в которой возникает ошибка:

```
def assert_called_once_with(self, /, *args, **kwargs):
    """assert that the mock was called exactly once and that that call was
    with the specified arguments."""
    if not self.call_count == 1:
        msg = ("Expected '%s' to be called once. Called %s times.%s"
               % (self._mock_name or 'mock',
                  self.call_count,
                  self._calls_repr()))
        raise AssertionError(msg)
    return self.assert_called_with(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, была не верная структура `RAW_EVENT`

```
class Test1(TestCase):
    RAW_EVENT = {
        'type': 'message_new',
        'object': {
            'message': {
                'date': 1582986599, 'from_id': ******, 'id': 72, 'out': 0, 'peer_id': ********,
                'text': 'sefsef', 'conversation_message_id': 71, 'fwd_messages': [], 'important': False,
                'random_id': 0, 'attachments': [], 'is_hidden': False},
            'client_info': {
                'button_actions': ['text', 'vkpay', 'open_app', 'location', 'open_link'],
                'keyboard': True, 'inline_keyboard': True, 'lang_id': 0}
        },
        'group_id': *****, 'event_id': 'c718db427a53d74ce7acad554014671894b0b84f'}

    def test_run(self):
        count = 5
        obj = {'a': 1}
        events = [obj] * count  # [obj, obj, ...]
        long_poller_mock = Mock(return_value=events)
        long_poller_listen_mock = Mock()
        long_poller_listen_mock.listen = long_poller_mock

        with patch('bot.vk_api.VkApi'):
            with patch('bot.VkBotLongPoll', return_value=long_poller_listen_mock):
                bot = Bot('', '')
                bot.on_event = Mock()
                bot.run()

                bot.on_event.assert_called()
                bot.on_event.assert_called_with(obj)

                assert bot.on_event.call_count == count

    def test_on_event(self):
        event = VkBotMessageEvent(raw=self.RAW_EVENT)

        send_mock = Mock()

        with patch('bot.vk_api.VkApi'):
            with patch('bot.VkBotLongPoll'):
                bot = Bot('', '')
                bot.api = Mock()
                bot.api.messages.send = send_mock

                bot.on_event(event)

        send_mock.assert_called_once_with(
            message=self.RAW_EVENT['object']['message']['text'],
            random_id=ANY,
            peer_id=self.RAW_EVENT['object']['message']['peer_id']
        )
```